# Passing params in createlink tag using jQuery

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I'm trying to do a very easy thing, but I'm stuck and I feel so stupid.
Basically I have a text area defined like this:

```
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control" rows="7"></textarea>
```

Then I have a createlink tag where I would like to pass in the params section the content of the textarea, so I did something like this:

```
<g:createLink controller="admin"
              action="book"
              id="${bookingInstance?.id}"
              params="jQuery('#comment').serialize()"/>
```

Of course it doesn't work. 
Can anybody give me some advices?

thanks a lot

nibe

UPDATE:
the create link it's inside a html  tag. Like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-centered" onclick="getComment();" title="Press me" href=
<g:createLink
   controller="admin"
   action="bookAccepted"
   id="${bookingInstance?.id}"/>>
  Press me
 </a>
```

The getComment() function is defined like this:

```
function getComment() {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href') + '?' + $('#commet').serialize();
    return false;
}
```

As result I got this error message:
Provided id of the wrong type for class com.Booking. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows:Message: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.Booking. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to do this with jQuery. So something like this perhaps:

```
<g:link controller="admin" action="book" id="${bookingInstance?.id"} onclick="return function() { window.location.href=$(this).attr('href') + '?' + $('#comment').serialize(); return false;}">My link</g:link>
```

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks for the answer, but as far as I know createLink doesn't allow onclick event.  I moved out side in the <a> tag. But still I got an error message:Provided id of the wrong type for class com.xxx.Booking. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows:

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I was thinking of g:link which does in fact allow that. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try use JS like that. Works fine for me, of course, for ajax call.

```
function sendTextArea(comment) {
     var params = {"comment":comment, "id": ${bookingInstance?.id}};
     console.log(params);
     ${remoteFunction(controller: 'admin', action: 'book', params:'params', update:'div')}
}
```